How to use decltype when the related data is defined later with C++11?
How to make the code snippet below compile with C++11 without writing the member varaible firstly? It looks ugly to write member variales before member functions.
#include <vector>

class Demo
{
public:
    decltype(m_data) foo(){
        return m_data;
    };
private:
    std::vector<int> m_data;
};

int main() {
    // Your main code goes here
    Demo demo;
    auto data = demo.foo();
    return 0;
}

For C++14, this code works:
#include <vector>

class Demo {
public:
    decltype(auto) foo();
private:
    std::vector<int> m_data;
};

decltype(auto) Demo::foo() {
    return m_data;
}

int main() {
    Demo demo;
    auto data = demo.foo();
    // Your main code goes here
    return 0;
}


" It looks ugly..." That is subjective. What is the real problem?

"It looks ugly to write member variales..." Define ugly. What ugly to you may be ideal to other. Will writing typedefs before instead of member variables before member functions will be ugly?

@user12002570 In general, member functions are written before member variables.

In C++14, class Demo { public: auto foo() { return m_data; } private: std::vector<int> m_data; }; also works


It looks ugly to write member variables before member functions

If you don't want to write member variables before than you can provide typedefs etc before member functions as shown below:
class Demo
{
private:
   //provide all typedefs/aliases here 
   using vec_t = std::vector<int>;
public:
//---vvvv--------->use typedef name
     vec_t foo()
     {
        return m_data;
     }
private:
    
    vec_t m_data;
};


Thank you for the repaid replay. I did a little modification.

@John I see. Yeah, that was a good edit.

In C++11 I would do this ;
#include <vector>
#include <type_traits>

class Demo
{
using my_collection_t = std::vector<int>;

public:
    my_collection_t foo() 
    {
        return m_data;
    };
private:
     my_collection_t  m_data;
};

int main() {
    // Your main code goes here
    Demo demo;
    auto data = demo.foo();
    return 0;
}

But I would be even more inclined to update my language version

What's <type_traits> do here?

Left over from another small experiment ;)

@PepijnKramer Isnt this the same as my answer expect the name of the typedef?

Returning std::vector but also a check in foo like this static_assert(std::is_same_v<std::vector<int>,decltype(m_data)>::value);... but the using statement is much cleaner

@user12002570 Yes I was writing it when your answer was not there yet...  ;) ... I would use a more unique name than type for your using statement though

@PepijnKramer Updated, changed the name to vec_t.

I don't see a problem with defining properties before methods.
That said, it can be argued that defining public portion before the private one is a better practice since it contributes to readability of the class.
In your code snippet, what is the purpose of using auto rather than using std::vector<int> directly or via using ? If it's to generalize the usage for different types, then templates are much better candidate for that - make that type a template parameter and use it everywhere inside instead of deducing via decltype.

I see it as a way to keep the code DRY.  If you decide later on int needs to become int64_t only having to make that change in one place is really nice.
